# Python Popen, OS, Commands all return nothing when running a command in linux

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

So I need to get the version of something on a client and when I try to use Popen, Call, Check_Call, OS, Commands it all returns a value of nothing. When I run the script on a system in putty it returns me an empty line. Can it be because of putty?. Running on Linux, CentOS if that makes any difference. Thank you guys ahead of time.

```
def getJavacVer():
    p = sp.Popen("javac -version", stdout=sp.PIPE, shell=True)
    (output, err) = p.communicate()
    print output
```

Comment: Possible solution might be giving complete path for "javac". Also, PIPE stderr as well and check it. You might find something there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `javac` program returns the `-version` output through `stderr`, so `stderr` argument of `Popen` also need to be passed. Try:

```
>>> from subprocess import Popen
>>> from subprocess import PIPE
>>> p = Popen(['javac', '-version'], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
>>> p.communicate()
(b'', b'javac 1.8.0_171\n')
```

The second element is of the result is the captured output of the `stderr` stream, which contains the version number.

Comment: Wow okay, this is very interesting. Thank you for awnsering my question. I have a secondary question is there any reason for it returning it to stderr?

Comment: The developers behind it might think that those particular output don't belong to the standard stream - however, these kind of decisions are up to whoever that wrote the program so you will have to ask them.

Answer (score 0):

This will only work on *nix:

```
import commands
print commands.getstatusoutput('javac -version')
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to the few fellas that answered the question. The output is being put out to stderr instead of stdout. Thank you to everyone